# Capture a keyboard event in a UI panel?

Tags: python

I was wondering if in a UI panel it is possible to capture a keyboard event

I am aware that this can be done in an operator in the invoke function like this:

```
def invoke(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'A':
        print("Example A")
    if event.type == 'B':
        print("Example B")
```

But I would like to do it in a panel, and I don't know if it's possible, in case I would like to clear up any doubts about it, I would like to do something like this:

(My example is incorrect, `event.type` doesn't exist, but that's for illustration purposes only)

```
import bpy

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "LayoutDemoPanel"
    bl_idname = "LayoutDemoPanel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "LayoutDemoPanel"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        


        # If button 'A' is pressed
        if event.type == 'A':
            self.layout(text="Example A")
        # If button 'B' is pressed
        if event.type == 'B':
            self.layout(text="Example B")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hello, UI related methods don't have access to keyboard events, you can either use a modal operator running in the background (I wouldn't advise to do it, it disables auto save feature) or define a keymap item that will trigger an operator and change a property stored somewhere (usually in the scene custom props) to toggle panel behaviour

Comment: Hello. It might be an interesting idea, but I wouldn't want to cause problems for users with a modal. At the moment the invoke method I mentioned is exactly inside an operator, which by pressing a key does something different

Comment: I *think* you can use a keymap item to directly change a property value without using an operator, however I don't remember the syntax

Comment: Here it is ! https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/keymap_editing.html#key-bindings-for-properties

Comment: Well it is an operator, but you don't have to define a new one

Comment: @Gorgious How does this help my question? I don't understand what I should be looking for in the link you provided, sorry for asking but I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Well the answer to your question is no, so i suggested you create a custom keymap entry to toggle values stored in your blend file. There are builtin operators that let you specify a custom path to tweak properties stored on your blend file so you don't have to define a bunch of operators for each custom entry. See this answer for a practical example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98930/86891